How to auto start build agent in interactive mode after restart windows VM
I want to automate the start of the build agent in interactive mode after restarting the Windows VM.
Could you please tell me how I should automate this? I tried using PowerShell's Start Process command, but it didn't help.

As mentioned below, you can configure the self-hosted Windows agent as Interactive mode with autologon enabled @Tamilselvan

When you configure a self-hosted Windows agent as Interactive mode, you can also configure it to auto-logon and run the agent on startup by entering 'Y' (YES) for the option "Enter configure autologon and run agent on startup? (Y/N)". Then enter the User account and Password to logon the agent machine.

You also can directly pass the argument '--runAsAutoLogon' to '.\config.cmd' when starting to configure the agent.
.\config.cmd --runAsAutoLogon

For more details, you can see "Windows-only startup".

EDIT:
For the interactive mode self-hosted Windows agent with autologon enabled, every time when the agent machine is startup, a command window is automatically opened to start and logon the agent, and then listens if there is any pipeline job in queue needs to run on this agent.
If you want to keep the agent online, you need to persist the command window open. Once the command window is closed, the agent will offline.
There are no other ways to keep the interactive mode self-hosted Windows agent online unless you re-configure it to be service mode. However, the service mode agent might not be able to correctly run some steps that need interactive operations.


is there any other way to keep the interactive agent in online ?

@Tamilselvan, If you want to keep the interactive agent online, you need to persist the command window open. Once the command window is closed, the agent will offline. For more details, see EDIT in my answer above.
